# Creating a notification with a pending intent

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

SO I am fairly new to android and I am trying to make a button create a notification and then clicking on this notification makes a call. I've done a lot of looking around online and I still can't figure out why this is not working. I have this method.

```
   public void notification(){
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel: 0210000001"));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, callIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                    .setContentTitle("My notification")
                    .setContentText("Click to ring 021 000 0001")
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
}
```

and this button that calls the method.

```
Button notif = (Button) findViewById(R.id.notificationButton);
    notif.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            notification();
        }
    });}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can read this documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the notification from your `NotificationBuilder` and then notify.

```
Notification mNotification = mBuilder.build();
mNotification.notify();

NotificationManager mManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mManager.notify(1234, mNotification);
```

The number `1234` is a random arbitrary number to identify this notification from your process. You can put any number and not worry about it unless later you want to manipulate this specific notification (like cancel it).